# what is the reason of getting segmentation fault in this code?

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault

i coded this to multiply 2 matrices by multi threading it takes row and column of each matrices from users and randomly create two matrices. it is the first time i am getting segmentation fault and i searched alot about that why segmentation fault happen but i could not solve this. now i need your idea that what should i do. i debugged each line of code by gdb and i get segmentation fault on 89th line like this:

```
**[New Thread 0x7ffff7dca700 (LWP 7323)] [New Thread 0x7ffff75c9700 (LWP 7324)] [New Thread 0x7ffff6dc8700 (LWP 7325)] [New Thread 0x7ffff65c7700 (LWP 7326)] Thread 1 "test" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x00007ffff7f9d297 in __pthread_clockjoin_ex (threadid=8, 
        thread_return=0x0, clockid=0, abstime=0x0, block=true)
        at pthread_join_common.c:89 89      pthread_join_common.c: No such   file or directory.**
```

the code is:

```
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <time.h>
    
    #define MAT_SIZE 10
    #define MAX_THREADS 100
    
    int r1,c1,r2,c2,c,k,d;           //Parameters For Rows And Columns
    int matrix1[MAT_SIZE][MAT_SIZE]; //First Matrix
    int matrix2[MAT_SIZE][MAT_SIZE]; //Second Matrix
    int result [MAT_SIZE][MAT_SIZE]; //Multiplied Matrix
    
    //Type Defining For Passing Function Argumnents
    typedef struct parameters {
    int x,y;
    }args;
    
    int random_num() {
    return rand() % 10;
    }
```

Comment: `for(int a=0;a<r1;a++){ for(int a=0;a<c2;a++){ ` is very strange, are you sure so use the 'right version' of *a* in `sum+= matrix1[p->x][a]*matrix2[a][p->y];`?

Comment: Good spot: the outer loop's `a` will be ignored (shadowed), leading to possible indexing out of range, when the value of the inner `a` is `>= r1`.

Comment: i solved that error but now i am getting this error [New Thread 0x7ffff7dca700 (LWP 7323)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff75c9700 (LWP 7324)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff6dc8700 (LWP 7325)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff65c7700 (LWP 7326)]

Thread 1 "test" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7f9d297 in __pthread_clockjoin_ex (threadid=8, 
    thread_return=0x0, clockid=0, abstime=0x0, block=true)
    at pthread_join_common.c:89
89      pthread_join_common.c: No such file or directory.

Comment: @andkhoycoding first I do not understand why you undeleted to remove almost all the code in your question, now the code you give contains absolutely nothing executed => it is impossible to have a segmentation fault in this condition ! Second, you cannot reuse an old question for a new problem, open a new question with  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this is absolutely not the case currentely

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that all your threads are set up with

```
pthread_create(&thread[thread_number], ...
```

where `thread_number` does not vary, so the thread handles are all overwritten bar the last. When you try to clean up

```
pthread_join(thread[z], NULL);
```

for `z=0 .. z<thread_number`, you exclude the only thread handle you actually initialized.

Other problems are:

- the question includes swathes of irrelevant interactive input code that cannot possibly be required to reproduce the problem

  Reducing code to the minimum needed to reproduce the problem is an important step in understanding it, even if you don't end up posting it online.
- it uses global variables instead of the thread parameters (which are set up and then ignored)

  Reducing or avoiding the use of shared global variables - *especially* in multi-threaded code - makes life much easier by limiting the number of places a mutation can happen. The posted code will have multiple threads trying to overwrite the same results.
- indentation is all over the place

  Indenting code correctly makes it easier to read (for everyone), which also makes it easier to spot bugs.